# I trying on Windows 10, Trying to connect / login to work interactively on container but I'm getting this kind of error

Tags: docker, php, docker-machine

I trying on Windows 10, Trying to connect / login to work interactively on container but I'm getting this kind of error

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:80 laravel-docker
 Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint wizardly_diffie (0c95bf862e583179e0a988eae0b07606e41184548c494ddd523df95c1430422f): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:8080:tcp:172.17.0.8:80: input/output error.
```

How to resolve this.

my docker version

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
```

Answer (score 1):

Restart docker, it falls into this state after the OS reboots.

The below thread mentions running it a swarm as preventing the issue from reoccurring and several ways to resolve the underlying OS issue with the software that may, or may not be workable for you.

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1038